# Visual Studio 2015 vNext and Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, visual-studio-2015

How do I configure a project to use Windows Authentication? Now that there are no web.config files, I cannot see how to do this.

I see the app.UseIdentity() in Startup, but no idea how to use Windows Auth with IIS Express. When I try to create a project in IIS (Windows 7, IIS 7.5), there does not appear to be a .NET 4.6/4.5 app pool I tried .NET 4.0 but get an error:

> Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742 for more information.

Of course, that link does not bring me to info, but to http://www.asp.net/

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me in debugging with VS2015:

Open the IIS Express config file: `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

There's a line that says:
`<windowsAuthentication enabled="false">`

Change it to:
`<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">`

Then I added to my Web.conf:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
<authorization>
</authorization>
```

I was then able to pull the windows username with:
 `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`

Comment: This appears to be the VS2013 location for `application.config`.  The VS2015 location is in the hidden `.vs\config` directory of the solution.

Comment: I can't speak as to the why, but this was in VS2015 Professional

Answer (score 1):

Go to web project properties -> Debug -> IIS Express Settings part and there <s>uncheck Enable Anonymous Authentication and</s> Check Enable Windows Authentication.

User (in controllers) will be loaded with local domain data.

http://screencast.com/t/GecnmVnXHC

**edit**:
We had to Enable Anonymous Authentication as a CORS preflight request would fail otherwise (401)

Answer (score -2):

There is a config file for IISExpress too. See a guide here: See [Using Windows Authentication with IISExpress](http://www.danesparza.net/2014/09/using-windows-authentication-with-iisexpress/)

Comment: You should provide more detail on how this is done, rather than completely relying on a link to an external site.

Comment: He is stuck because there is no config file, i said there was, the link was just a bonus...

Comment: Simply saying "there is a config file" isn't very helpful. Where is it? What settings should be changed to enable Windows authentication?